# How to get Data form a table based on the foreign key in sql

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Here wish to get the data from Table 1 which is created between 5\09\2018 to 26\12\2018.
Here PostID is the foreign key.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both tables and use where statement to retrieve the relevant data,

```
Select * 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.PostID=t2.PostID
where t1.datecreated between '2018-09-05' and  '2018-12-26'
```

Comment: Don't put parenthesis around the range for `BETWEEN`.

Comment: yes, i was about to change that thanks for notifying

Answer (score 1):

Select * 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.PostID=t2.PostID
where t2.PostID=1

For inner join foreign key is mandatory, and the reference column will come in the join condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you just query data from Table 1, you may write the query like this.

```
select 
* 
from table1 T
where T.DateCreated between '2018-09-05 00:00:00' and '2018-12-26 23:59:59'
and exists (select 1 from table2 where PostID=T.PostID)
```

Best Regards,

Will